# Given n points, how can I find the number of points with given distance

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, coordinates, distance

I have an input of *n* **unique** points (X,Y) that are between 0 and 2^32 inclusive. **The coordinates are integers.**

I need to create an algorithm that finds the number of **pairs of points with a distance of *exactly* 2018**.

I have thought of checking with every other point but it would be *O(n^2)* and I have to make it more efficient. I also thought of using a set or a vector and sort it using a comparator based on the distance with the origin point but it wouldn't help at all.

So how can I do it efficiently?

Comment: integer or float?  If it is integer grid and requires exact distance then it is simpler.

Comment: it is only integer

Comment: Pythagoras is your friend

Comment: @start I think the OP is quite aware of how to calculate the distance between two points. The question is about how to solve the problem with a minimum number of such calculations, not about how to do such a calculation in the first place

Comment: Does it have to be less than O(n²) in the worst case, or only in typical cases?

Comment: I know it has to run with a maximum of 10^5 in under 3 seconds

Comment: One algorithm I can think of is: for each point, say p, find the points which lie on the circle of radius 2018 with center of the circle being p. But, the complexity will be probably not what you want.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the points are unique?

Comment: yes, its guarranteed

Comment: One idea it come to my mind, is to create bounding boxes that groups up points that are close to each other. So every time a new point is evaluated you first check if its inside a bounding box. If it's not inside means he won't collide with anyone. If it's inside, then you'll need to check 1 by 1 with all the points inside the box.

Comment: Are your numbers integers or floating point? And are you looking for the exact or the maximum distance of 2018?

Comment: @AleixRius That works only if the points are fairly evenly distributed in a much larger area than that 2018 distance. If all points are within, say, a circle of radius of 5000, then dividing into boxes does not help any, algorithm still becomes about O(n²).

Comment: @AleixRius on the other hand, if points are spread accross, say, a circle of radius 1,000,000,000, you need 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 smaller boxes of size 1000, which is clearly not practical (you'd need some kind of map for the boxes to exclude empty boxes, and accessing that would be slow.

Comment: @Yep I edited the question and added some emphasis for clarity. Please check I did not understand wrong (and roll back my edit if I did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one Pythagorean triple with the hypotenuse of 2018: 1118<sup>2</sup>+1680<sup>2</sup>=2018<sup>2</sup>.

Since all coordinates are integers, the only possible differences between the coordinates (both X an Y) of the two points are 0, 1118, 1680, and 2018.

Finding all pairs of points with a given difference between X (or Y) coordinates is a simple `n log n` operation.

Numbers other than 2018 might need a bit more work because they might be members of more than one Pythagorean triple (for example 2015 is a hypotenuse of 3 triples). If the number is not given as a constant, but provided at run time, you will have to generate all triples with this hypotenuse. This may require some `sqrt(N)` effort (N is the hypotenuse, not the number of points). One can find a recipe on the math stackexchange, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525605/generating-all-pythagorean-triplets-for-given-hypotenuse) (there are many others).

Comment: That's a brilliant solution! However it will only work for 2018 (you also have a typo there). You could make your answer even more useful for the generalized problem if you describe how to find pythagorean triplets. There is a formula described on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple). Yet I think this is the most elegant and easiest to implement solution so far.

Comment: @JakobStark Other numbers might be hypotenuses of more than one Pythagorean triples (for example 2015 is a hypotenuse of 4 such triples). So this could be a bit more difficult with the generalised problem. BTW if you see a typo just correct it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to edit your question (it says "suggested edit queue is full"). You wrote 1118^2+1680^2=2108^2. It should be ...=2018^2

Comment: also a difference of 2048 and 0 but yeah that's the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). First you start sorting your points into the quadtree. You should specify a lower limit for the cell size of e.g. 2048 wich is a power of 2. Then iterate though the points and calculate distances to the points in the same cell and to the points in adjacent cells. That way you should be able to decrease the number of distance calculations drastically.

The main difficulty will probably be implementing the tree structure. You also have to find a way to find adjacent cells (you must include the possibility to traverse upwards in the tree)

[image: quadtree_image]

The complexity of this is probably O(n*log(n)) in the best case but don't pin me down on that.

One additional word on the distance calculation: You are probably much faster if you don't do

```
dx = p1x - p2x;
dy = p1y - p2y;
if ( sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) == 2018 ) {
    ...
}
```

but

```
dx = p1x - p2x;
dy = p1y - p2y;
if ( dx*dx + dy*dy == 2018*2018 ) {
    ...
}
```

Squaring is faster than taking the sqare root. So just compare the square of the distance with the square of 2018.

Comment: Agree on not using square roots but the square distance.

Comment: "The complexity of this is probably O(n*log(n))" No. Not in the worst case.